# How to create an appointment from other application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to call Calendar from my simple application in iPhone. all sample out there give me a clue to use UIApplication#openURL function. How about if i want to open a calendar with/without a new event?

```
'[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8004664411"]];'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a document that lists all of the [URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) the current iPhone OS supports.  Unfortunately, there isn't one for the calendar, just

- Mail Links
- Phone Links
- Text Links
- Map Links
- YouTube Links
- iTunes Links

so it looks like you can't do it, at least not by launching a URL.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no API or URL scheme for accessing the calendar information on the phone. If you need one you should file a [bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) describing why you need it.